# Just lauched website, problems in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, wordpress

A website I just launched for a client is not rendering properly in Internet Explorer.  It works in all browsers except IE.

Comment: It centers, just be sure to get out of quirks mode.

Comment: stupid mistake, my apologies. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In line 1 `<link rel>` tag is defined, so your browser do not detect doctype and goes to [**quirks mode**](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html).

**See below:**

```
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://pacayamountaincoffee.com/wp-content/themes/pacayamountaincoffee/favicon.ico" />
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

**Your `<link rel>` tag should be inside `<head>` tag**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">    
 <head>    
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://pacayamountaincoffee.com/wp-content/themes/pacayamountaincoffee/favicon.ico" />
 </head>
```

Comment: oops.  Nice to have another pair of eyes. Thank you very much!